# Office js "UPDATE ADD-IN" startup message

Tags: office-js

We are using Office js for addin. We are getting the following message always when we try to load the excel addin initially.

"UPDATE ADD-IN"

"An update is required for this add-in. Features, terms of use and other details may have changed."

Any idea on why it is appearing always? We have enabled Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument to true on the document. I believe that doesn't have any impact on the message appearing.

Comment: Is this an add-in you are creating and sideloading? Are you using Visual Studio and F5? Of some other way of sideloading?

Comment: This occurs after deploying the add-in. Always add-in shows up this message for the users when they try to load the add-in. 
We have menu bar also which will show this addin. When the users load the addin from the menu bar this issue doesn't happen but on auto-load this happens at the startup.

Comment: How did you deploy the add-in? Central deployment? Network shared folder? What platform are your users using? Office Online? Office 2013? Office 2026 MSI? Office 2016 Click-to-Run? For one of the files on which this happens, change it's extension to .zip. Extract the files in the zip. Find the <we:webextension > element that has the id of your add-in. See if the version of the add-in there matches the version in the add-in manifest that you have deployed.

Comment: We deploy the website in IIS. Add-in manifest is deployed in office 365. Users install (one time) from ADMIN MANAGED from My Add-ins . I will check the version mismatch and see if there is any discrepancy.